# How to solve for the coefficients of this polynomial?

Tags: calculus, polynomials

> For what values of the constants $a$, $b$, $c$, and $d$ does the function $f(x) = ax^3 + bx^2 + cx + d$ satisfy both of the following conditions?
>
> **a)** $f''(0) = 0$ at the origin
>
> **b)** a horizontal tangent at $(2,4)$

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Walkthrough:

1. Calculate the second derivative of $f$ and use the information in "a)" to figure out a relation between two of the constants.
2. Calculate the first derivative of $f$ and use the information in "b)" (the shape of the tangent) to figure out a relation between 3 constants.
3. Use the information in "b)" (the position of a point on the function's graph) to figure out a second relation between 3 constants.
4. There is no unique answer, since we've got only 3 linear equations for 4 unknowns. The two relations you get in the previous steps give you the solution space.

Comment: Thank You. I did exactly what you did above and reached the same conclusion, buy my teacher insisted it's solvable. Are you certain she is wrong?

Comment: Oops - I made a mistake and posted too soon; edited.

Comment: @asdf Can you find more than one solution?

Comment: @GitGud Nope, she insisted that there was only solution for the constants.

Comment: @asdf, that depends on the meaning of "at the origin" in condition "a)". Does the function's graph have to pass through the origin, or only its second derivative? If the function's graph has to pass through the origin, then you can extract a 4th equation and get a unique solution. Otherwise - try walking through the steps, and you should be able to find two different solutions which you can check satisfy the conditions.

Comment: For instance, the constant function $4$ and the function $-2x^3 + 6x^2 - 4$ both satisfy the conditions. (Neither passes through the origin though.)

Comment: @YoniRozenshein The graph of the function does not have to pass through the origin (only the second derivative does). She probably made a mistake somewhere. Thank you for the help!